# Date plus 30 days validation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, yii

I am trying to write a validation rule in Yii but can't get the date compare to work.  Looking to render the error message if `End` is not greater than 30 days past `Start`.

```
public function checkDate($attribute,$params)
    {
        $duration = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->Start)) . ' +30 days');
        if ($this->End < $duration) 
                $this->addError('End','30 days or more!');
    }
```

With this every input yields the error message.  I am using a MySql db and Start and End are `date` format

**EDIT:**
Given the input in the answers below I have tried

This will not even render the page now.

```
    $startDate = $this->Start;
    $endDate = $this->End;
    $interval = $startDate->diff($endDate);
    if ($interval < 30) 
                $this->addError('End','30 days or more!');
```

and

This gives the error 100% of the time.

```
$duration = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->Start . '+ 30 days'));
if ($this->End < $duration) 
    $this->addError('End','30 days or more!');
```

Comment: Be careful using strtotime to validate user input see [strtotime Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) `The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC.`  if you can use php [Datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Mind explaining why and or giving alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are compairing `$duration` to `$this->END`(which comes right out of the database) you need to put `date('Y-m-d', $duration)` before you check against `$this->END`
you're compairing a strtotime to a `date('Y-m-d')` where are apples and oranges

change
$duration = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->Start)) . ' +30 days');
to
$duration = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->START . '+ 30 days'));

and your script should work

hope this helps

Comment: This is for validating a form with user input. So I am trying to validate the user input, not db content.

Comment: your line:
$duration = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->Start)) . ' +30 days');
returns a unix timestamp
if you compair that to YYYY-MM-DD the timestamp will always be greater

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited my question to show the changes and results. Error always displays.

Comment: whatr does the output of $duration and $this->END look like in your script? (use echo $duration; echo $this->END)
are they both in date format?

Comment: Yes I should have added that I did validate that the variables were working.  But I failed to realize that I was getting two different date formats so var_dump($this->End < $duration); was always coming up true.  I will get the date formats the same and everything should work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
#source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited my question to show the changes and results.  Not sure if I am using it correctly but the page would not render and logs are not showing why.

Comment: `var_dump($interval);
$days_diff = $interval->d;
echo $days_diff;`

Comment: Also attention on property `invert`

Comment: Thanks for the help here, see my response to AMayer.  Both your answers bring me to what I need so I appreciate the help. +1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [DateTime->diff](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and check if the difference of days is less 30 then trigger an error

Answer (score 0):

I'm already using this in the following way:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
    ...
        array('dateX','timeoutSomething'),
    ...
    );
}


public function timeoutSomething($dateX){
    // If you try to modify the model after 300 seconds the error arise
    if((strtotime($this->dateX)+300) < time()){
        $this->addError($dateX,"Timeout exceed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for in this scenario but very helpful none the less in many other circumstances.  I will put it to good use.